# Two commands or command pipe command - Spawn Expect

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, expect

I'm trying to execute a expect script into bash script, but when I try to execute the shell without "`| tee -a xxx.log`" (where xxx.log is a file than I want to write to record the ssh session).

This code works fine:

```
comlog="ssh $USR@192.168.228.20"
expect -c"
    spawn \"$comlog\"
    expect \"Password:\"
    send \"$PASS\r\"
    interact
"
```

But when I try to add the "tee -a" command to save the ssh session the issue is

```
invalid command name "ssh"
while executing
```

This is the complete command where I obtain the error message

```
 comlog="ssh $USR@192.168.228.20 | tee -a /home/xxx.log"
 expect -c"
    spawn \"$comlog\"
    expect \"Password:\"
    send \"$PASS\r\" #Already Obteined
    interact
 "
```

I tried to change the "comlog" var as this ways but doesn't work :(

```
 cssh $USR@192.168.228.20 \| tee -a /home/xxx.log
```

Does anyone know another way to save the ssh session started from expect? Or how can I send those two commands in same spawn command.

Comment: Have you explored setting up public key authentication to avoid using `expect` at all?

Comment: Because I'm system administrator to generate the public key for that server :( 

I need to connect to that server frequently

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle multiple Spawn process in expect script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820661/handle-multiple-spawn-process-in-expect-script)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put shell metacharacters like the pipe, you'll have to spawn a shell to handle them. Also using a here-doc can help a lot with quoting

```
comlog="ssh $USR@192.168.228.20 | tee -a /home/xxx.log"
expect <<"END_EXPECT"
spawn sh -c "$comlog"
... rest of expect script
END_EXPECT
```

Comment: glen_jackman new error :(
     invalid command name "END_EXPECT"
     while executing
     "END_EXPECT"

Comment: Make sure there is no extra whitespace on the END_EXPECT line - do not indent it

Comment: This is the code (I can't paste it as I have it)

     comlog="ssh $USR@192.168.228.20 | tee -a /home/xxx.log"

     /usr/bin/expect <<<"END_EXPECT"
     spawn sh -c "$comlog"
     expect "Password:"
     send "$PASSMX\r"
     sleep 20
     send "1\r"
     interact
     END_EXPECT

Comment: My error, use `<<` not `<<<` -- with 2 symbols it's a here-doc, but with 3 it's a here-string, so I was sending the literal string "END_EXPECT" as the entire expect script. I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the expect session output this way:

```
 comlog="ssh $USR@192.168.228.20"
 expect -c"
    spawn \"$comlog\"
    expect \"Password:\"
    send \"$PASS\r\" #Already Obteined
    interact
 " >/home/xxx.log
```